# Clean up/Refresh Tray Area in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, system-tray, systray

When either hiding my tray icon and closing the application, half the time my application's tray icon gets 'stuck'. Meaning doesn't leave until you mess around in the tray area.

I know that to clean up *during **closing*** I can do `trayIcon.Dispose()` but that only works for when i close my C# application, and not for when I hide (`trayIcon.Visible = false`) it.

Does anyone know of a hack, or anyway at all, that can be used to refresh the tray area, or just make sure my icon actually stops displaying?

Comment: So your tray icon hangs around during a normal run of your application?  It's quite normal for the icon to stay around when debugging if you bail out before the app. can quit normally.

Comment: Sorry, I rephrased that first part to be more clear. I meant often times the tray icon does not actually disappear or hide itself when you close the application or hide the tray icon.

Comment: What is a tray icon? Are you talking about the **taskbar notification area**? It's not called the "tray" or "system tray" and it has *never* been called that. Please use precise terminology in your questions to ensure that people know what you're talking about.

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't sure about the "precise terminology". No need to downvote the question or tear into me just because I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Refreshing the Taskbar Notification Area in C#](http://safari-tech.serveblog.net/?p=101)

Comment: The link is broken